# PHP - parse a csv file and write output to another csv file

Tags: php, magento, csv

I am working on Magento products csv file and i have a csv file with 3 columns like

```
<pre>Name, description, Color</pre>
<pre>t-shirt, tshirt description, "green, blue, yellow"</pre>
```

Now based on the values of column 3rd column (color) i want to output each row in a separate file say "new_products.csv" in a manner so the resultant file would be like

```
<p>Name, description, Color</p>
<pre>t-shirt, tshirt description, green</pre>
<pre>t-shirt, tshirt description, blue</pre>
<pre>t-shirt, tshirt description, yellow</pre>
```

i have started with this code

```
$row = 1;

if (($handle = fopen("product.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
    $num = count($data);
            $name = $data[0];
    $desc = $data[1];

    for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {


        $fp = fopen('new_products.csv', 'w');

        if($c == 2){ //if we are at color field
            $color = explode(',', $data[$c]);
            $color_count = count($color);
            for($i=0; $i<$color_count; $i++){

                fputcsv($fp, array($name,$desc,$color[$i]));
            }

        }

    }
            $row++;
}
fclose($handle);
}
```

However the above code only outputting the last row only.

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried? Also, you might want to check [`fgetcsv`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php) and [`fputcsv`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php).

Comment: This is not a new problem - there are several answers on SO. I won't downvote as you're new (in terms of rep) but I would suggest you do some searching.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally i have been able to find the solution my self. Actually one need to set the file pointer at the end of the file.

```
$row = 1;

if (($handle = fopen("test.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
    $num = count($data);
    $name = $data[0];
    $desc = $data[1];


    for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {            

        if($c == 2){ //if we are at color field
          $fp = fopen('file.csv', 'a'); //Open for writing only; place the file pointer at the end of the file.
            $color = explode(',', $data[$c]);
            $color_count = count($color);
            for($i=0; $i<$color_count; $i++){
                fputcsv($fp, array($name,$desc,$color[$i]));
            }
            fclose($fp);
        }

    }

            $row++;
}
fclose($handle);
```

}